# Show json objects in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I need to load a JSON file from a remote link and show the information I want in the view.

In PHP I woud have done it like this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.bitlc.net/stats.json";

$json_stats=json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
$stats_data = get_object_vars($json_stats);

echo $stats_data[hash_rate];
?>
```

I searched online but have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it but here's an example using the `Mechanize` gem.

```
json = Mechanize.new.get('http://www.bitlc.net/stats.json').body
result = JSON.parse json
```

`result` will be a Ruby hash of the json and you can display it in your views however you'd like.

Comment: And to display it in my view how would i so that? like  <%= @result['hash_rate'] %>

Comment: Mechanize is major overkill to retrieve JSON. I'd recommend using Open::URI as a starting point. Simply `require 'open-uri'` then `json = open('http://www.bitlc.net/stats.json').read`. The command itself is similar, but Open::URI is lightweight.